# Using Custom Repository Implementation with Spring Data JPA while Retaining Built-in CRUD Methods

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use a custom repository implementation with Spring Data JPA without losing the convenience of the built-in CRUD methods? I need to add some custom logic to a repository, but I don't want to rewrite all the basic CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to make a custom repository implementation with Spring Data.

First - CustomizedRepository interface is created - it will provide interface for additional methods that are wanted to be created.

```
interface CustomizedRepository {
  void someCustomMethod(Entity entity);
}
```

Second - create class CustomizedRepositoryImpl which will implement both CustomizedRepository CrudRepository (to access Spring Data methods)

```
interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Long>, CustomizedRepository {

  // Query methods could be additionally declared here
}
```

[Here is a link to Spring Data documentation for reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)